# Finding image based on closest camera pose

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have a camera matrix world of a 3D scene (let's call it A):

```
[[ 6.86118087e-01 -7.27490186e-01  1.11022302e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 3.82193007e-01  3.60457832e-01  8.50881106e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-6.19007654e-01 -5.83804917e-01  5.25358300e-01  0.00000000e+00]
 [-2.89658661e+00  5.19178303e-01 -3.50478367e-02  1.00000000e+00]]
```

And, I have 1000 2D images of the scene. For each image, I have pose (camera to world) as follows:

```
[[-9.55421e-01  1.19616e-01 -2.69932e-01  2.65583e+00]
 [ 2.95248e-01  3.88339e-01 -8.72939e-01  2.98160e+00]
 [ 4.07581e-04 -9.13720e-01 -4.06343e-01  1.36865e+00]
 [ 0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  1.00000e+00]]
```

I want to find the image that is closest to A by comparing pose matrix. How do I compare A with the camera pose of each image?

What is closest?

Just a little background, we asked annotators to write descriptions of an object in a 3D scene. Along with that, we also captured camera parameters, such as matrix world (see A above), center, lookat, and dof, so that we can estimate where in 3D scene were they looking at when they wrote the description. So, now I am trying to create a training set of images (one image for each scene from 1000 available) and would like to find the image that best matches the recorded camera parameters.